# Make image appear on link hover css

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, hover

I am working with this, probably simple solution, but I couldn't find any help on stackoverflow or the internet relating to this specific problem.

I have a menu, and I want to make an image appear under the link or close by when you hover over it. I hope this can be done in CSS. This is my code so far.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="startpage.css">


        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="wrapper">


         <img id="baggrund" width="166" height="327" alt="back image" src="images/laerkeryg.jpg"/>
         <img id="cirkler" width="319" height="249" alt="circles" src="images/circles.PNG"/>
         <div id="header">/jacob gerlif pilegaard/</div>
         <div id="underheader">portfolio</div>   
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
            </ul> 
         </div>
     <img id="menucircle" width="50" height="50" alt="menu circle" src="images/circle.PNG"/>
          </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS so far:

```
a:hover
{
    background-image: url('image/circle.PNG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: seems to be working fine to me? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/wW8aW/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The clean way to deal with it is to use `:after` pseudo element

```
a:hover:after {
    content: url(image/circle.PNG); /* no need for qoutes */
    display: block;
}
```

You don't even need the image to be present in the DOM.
Also remember that the path to the image will be relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file.

Of course, the image will *push* down the content below the anchor. To avoid this you can try:

```
a:hover {
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
    content: url(image/circle.PNG); /* no need for qoutes */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 123px; /* change this value to one that suits you */
    top: 56px; /* change this value to one that suits you */
}
```

Comment: @tnkh can you explain what part of this example doesn't work for you in Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the image *within* the href and giving a style of 'display: none'

Then:

```
a:hover img{ display: block; }
```

That should display the image when hovering on the

Comment: This _could_ cause problems with [`SEO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). Giving the anchors a set height will make this obsolete and is more SEO friendly.

Answer (score 1):

For background-image you need to give the anchor a width, height (or relevant padding) and display it as a block.

```
a:hover
{
    background-image: url('image/circle.PNG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height:20px
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
```