# Showing image on hover over navigation bar

Tags: html, css, hover

I'am newbie to CSS .. and i want to add an image of bar over each element in the navigation bar which appear on hover and over selected element
like this

[image]

that's my HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/ecomm/public" class="selected">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about" >ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact" >CONTACT</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried the solution in this question [Make image appear on link hover css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270594/make-image-appear-on-link-hover-css) but it appeared once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pseudo` element on `hover`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align:center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul li a:hover, ul li a.selected{
  color:red;
}
ul li a.selected:before, ul li a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/ecomm/public" class="selected">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks .. it worked like Sharm .. but it there any way to make it appear over class selected permanently ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i did it with `border-top` http://jsfiddle.net/85d4tcjx/

```
ul{

text-align:center;
list-style-type:none;
}

li{
border-top:5px solid transparent;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
}

li:hover{
border-top:5px solid black;
}
```

With images try this http://jsfiddle.net/85d4tcjx/3/

```
li:hover{
border-image:url('http://www.mycelticcrossstitch.com/celtic%20knot%20cross%20stitch.jpg') 30 30  round;
border-image-width:5px 0 0 0;
 }
```