# Change size of an image appearing by hovering over text css

Tags: css, image, hover

I have a text on which when you hover (or when you click on it on mobile), a picture appear. I used this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270781) to make it work.

I'm now trying to make the picture change size automatically, so the picture fit both on mobile and computer.

```css
a.hovertext1:after {
  content: 'Text that appears before I hover.';
}

a.hovertext1:hover:after,
a.hovertext1:focus:after {
  content: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1074330512925143102/1076897722075971675/5226579-le-drapeau-national-de-la-republique-federative-du-bresil-fond-d-ecran-du-drapeau-bresilien-avec-des-styles-de-degrade-d-ombre-gratuit-vectoriel.jpg);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a name="return1" id="return1"></a>
<a href="#return1" class="hovertext1"></a>
```

I know I need to add `width:100%;` somewhere in my code, but I have no idea where. I tried putting it in the `a.hovertext1:focus:after{...}` block, but it didn't do anything.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a running example; would it be possible to upload the relevant image to your code (using the 'add image' button just above the [edit] window), or link to a suitably demonstrative image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason for which you want to use pseudo elements ? There is a different approach using simple display property on hover.

```css
img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover + img {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Text that appears before I hover</a>
<img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" />
```

Also I suggest to use buttons instead of links. Buttons are used for actions that affect the website’s front-end; links are used for navigation and actions that don’t affect the website.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work; hovering doesn't do anything on my laptop and clicking on it takes me back to the top of the page. Clicking on mobile also just makes the text disappear without displaying any picture. It's supposed to appear in the middle of a text (think article posted on a preexisting website). While I have control over the CSS for my text, I'm not sure how limited it is.

Comment: If you run the snippet, you will see that's working. You will have to improve the above code with pseudo class :focus and use media queries to adapt handling for mobile and desktop. I am not sure what you really want to achieve, but at some point, I think you will have to consider JavaScript as a better option.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the snippet doesn't work when I run it.

Comment: Removing the last a:hover block made it work. Thank you for the help.